# Sorting is not working on gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I added a sorting option in a GridView, but don't know why it isn't working.

This is my markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  AllowSorting="true" runat="server" Width="100%"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DefaultSortDirection="Ascending" DataKeyNames="ClientAccountNumber,Invoice" AllowPaging="true"OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting">
 <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Invoice" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="[Invoice]">
       <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblInvoice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Invoice")%>'></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>    
</Columns>
```

Code:

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
   // bindGrid();

    DataTable dataTable = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
    if (dataTable != null)
    {
        DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
        dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);
        GridView1.DataSource = dataView;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Code for binding the gridview

```
private void bindGrid()
{
    try
    {
        if (int.Parse(lblAccountNo.Text.ToString()) > 0)
        {
            _clientTransection.AccountNo  =Convert.ToInt32(lblAccountNo.Text.ToString());
           Collection<ClientTransInvoiceRows> _clientList =    _clientTransection.Execute();
           GridView1.DataSource = _clientList;
           GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

This line:

```
DataTable dataTable = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
```

is giving me null. Is there another option for sorting my GridView?

Comment: Define 'not working'..

Comment: Note: For memory saving you should use string.Format instead concatenating string by + operator. In this case isn't significant difference, but it's a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not going to work this way. `DataSource` property is not null only during data binding. In all other stages of page life-cycle (namely during events handling) it is null, unless you explicitly initialize it.

In your case however solution is simple enough - just rebind the grid the way you have binded it before, just taking into account sorting info. First modify the `bindGrid` method to take sorting into account.

```
private void bindGrid(string sort)
{
    try
    {
        if (int.Parse(lblAccountNo.Text.ToString()) > 0)
            _clientTransection.AccountNo = Convert.ToInt32(lblAccountNo.Text.ToString());
        Collection<ClientTransInvoiceRows> _clientList = _clientTransection.Execute();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sort))
        {
            // apply sorting
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = _clientList;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Then call it with appropriate params:

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    string sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);
    bindGrid(sort);
}
```

Comment: if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sort))
        {
            // apply sorting
        }  in this part what i need to do

Comment: @Abhishek, sort `_clientList` using sorting string. Maybe by casting to `DataTable` as you were trying before, maybe other way - depends on your situation and preferences.

Comment: i am getting error when i want to change  `Collection<ClientTransInvoiceRows> _clientList =    _clientTransection.Execute(); ` How can i convert this to `DataSet`

Comment: @Abhishek, not sure. If `Collection` is a BCL type here - it won't even be possible, not directly. I think your best bet is to refactor `_clientTransection.Execute` method to do sorting.